# How to pass persistent volume to postgres docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I want to run PostgreSql database with docker, I created a docker-compose like below:

```
    django:
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - pgdb
    #environment:
    #    - url=https://api.backend.example.com
    #command: "gunicorn config.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
    #networks:
    #   - bridge
pgdb:
    image: postgres
    container_name: pgdb
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=hbys_filyos
      - POSTGRES_USER=healmedy
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mhacare1
```

I want to run PostgreSql database with docker, I created a docker-compose like below:

After building I run docker run -p 80:8000 surgery4:dev & as follows.

I am getting the following error in terminal:

```
 django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "pgdb" to address: Try again
```

Answer (score 0):

There are indentation issue in your `docker-compose` file : `django` should be in proper place.

```
 django:
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - pgdb
    #environment:
    #    - url=https://api.backend.example.com
    #command: "gunicorn config.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
    #networks:
    #   - bridge
pgdb:
    image: postgres
    container_name: pgdb
    volumes:
      - pg-data/:/var/lib/postgresql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=hbys_filyos
      - POSTGRES_USER=healmedy
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mhacare1
```

Also you just need to execute : `docker-compose up -d` from where your `docker-compose` file located.

Comment: There was a small mistake while typing here, I don't have the django indentation problem in my code, it was misspelled while writing here. ERROR when run docker-compose up -d in terminal: Named volume "pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw" is used in service "pgdb" but no declaration was found in the volumes section. i get the error

Comment: Please try updated answer